# Limit on bz2 file decompression using python?

Tags: python, bz2

I have numerous files that are compressed in the bz2 format and I am trying to uncompress them in a temporary directory using python to then analyze. There are hundreds of thousands of files so manually decompressing the files isn't feasible so I wrote the following script.

My issue is that whenever I try to do this, the maximum file size is 900 kb even though a manual decompression has each file around 6 MB. I am not sure if this is a flaw in my code and how I am saving the data as a string to then copy to the file or a problem with something else. I have tried this with different files and I know that it works for files smaller than 900 kb. Has anyone else had a similar problem and knows of a solution?

My code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import bz2
import os
import glob

def unzip_f(filepath):
    '''
    Input a filepath specifying a group of Himiwari .bz2 files with common names
    Outputs the path of all the temporary files that have been uncompressed

    '''


    cpath = os.getcwd() #get current path
    filenames_ = []  #list to add filenames to for future use

    for zipped_file in glob.glob(filepath):  #loop over the files that meet the name criterea
        with bz2.BZ2File(zipped_file,'rb') as zipfile:   #Read in the bz2 files
            newfilepath = cpath +'/temp/'+zipped_file[-47:-4]     #create a temporary file
            with open(newfilepath, "wb") as tmpfile: #open the temporary file
                for i,line in enumerate(zipfile.readlines()):
                    tmpfile.write(line) #write the data from the compressed file to the temporary file



            filenames_.append(newfilepath)
    return filenames_


path_='test/HS_H08_20180930_0710_B13_FLDK_R20_S*bz2'
unzip_f(path_)
```

It returns the correct file paths with the wrong sizes capped at 900 kb.

Comment: Side-note: Get rid of the `enumerate` and `.readlines()`; you don't care about the line number, and `.readlines()` forces you to hold the whole decompressed file in memory, not just a line at a time (the file-like object already iterates by line, so forcing it to eagerly slurp to a `list` is just wasting memory).

Comment: Don't read binary data line by line. Use `shutil.copyfileobj()` to handle decompression efficiently. Or use the [`shutil` archive decompression functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.unpack_archive).

Comment: Also, `with bz2.open(zipped_file) as zipfile, open(newfilepath, 'wb') as tmpfile: shutil.copyfileobj(zipfile, tmpfile)` would be faster and simpler for that matter. (Looks like Martijn beat me to that suggestion).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Those suggestions help the efficiency but the files are still capping out at 900 KB for some reason.

Comment: What Python version are you using?  The bz2 implementation in 2.7 and 3.3 does not properly handle files created by certain compressors such as pbzip2 - see https://bugs.python.org/issue20781 for details.

Comment: I am using python 2.7 so that may be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this issue is due to the files being multi stream which does not work in python 2.7. There is more info [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue20781) as mentioned by jasonharper and [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue10900). Below is a solution just using the Unix command to decompress the bz2 files and then moving them to the temporary directory I want. It is not as pretty but it works.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
import shutil

def unzip_f(filepath):
    '''
    Input a filepath specifying a group of Himiwari .bz2 files with common names
    Outputs the path of all the temporary files that have been uncompressed

    '''


    cpath = os.getcwd() #get current path
    filenames_ = []  #list to add filenames to for future use

    for zipped_file in glob.glob(filepath):  #loop over the files that meet the name criterea
        newfilepath = cpath +'/temp/'   #create a temporary file
        newfilename = newfilepath + zipped_file[-47:-4]

        os.popen('bzip2 -kd ' + zipped_file)
        shutil.move(zipped_file[-47:-4],newfilepath)

        filenames_.append(newfilename)
    return filenames_



path_='test/HS_H08_20180930_0710_B13_FLDK_R20_S0*bz2'

unzip_f(path_)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation in Python2, where the `BZ2File` class doesn't support multiple streams.
This can be easily resolved by using `bz2file`, https://pypi.org/project/bz2file/, which is a backport of Python3 implementation and can be used as a drop-in replacement.

After running `pip install bz2file` you can just replace `bz2` with it:
`import bz2file as bz2` and everything should just work :)

The original Python bug report: https://bugs.python.org/issue1625